# Laravel - Eloquent 3 Table Query

Tags: php, laravel

I know there are several questions out there on 3 table joins, but the examples are simpler than my set up.

I have three tables: `Items`, `Attributes`, `Categories`.

```
`item.item_code = attributes.item_code`

`attributes.category_id = category.id`
```

Using eloquent, I can access attributes no problem with:

$items = Item::with('attributes')->paginate(15);

But I can't seem to get the relationship set correctly to retrieve the category name.

With a standard MySql query I'd use something like:

```
    SELECT category_name FROM items
    JOIN attributes on items.item_code = attributes.item_code
    JOIN categories on attributes.pg3_id = categories.id 
    WHERE items.item_code = 40992264
```

How do I achieve this using eloquent?

Edit - My bad - Totally messed up the SQL. Updated to reflect the correct table names and include the second join

Update

My models currently look like this:

```
class Attributes extends Model
{
    public function category(){

        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}

class Product extends Model
{
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class);
    }

}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Attributes::class);
    }
}
```

But this still isn't returning a result. I've tried using

`$items = Item::with('attributes.category')->get();`

as suggested, but this still throws an error. If I update the Product model to:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class);
    }
    public function category(){

        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

}
```

I don't get an error, but the relationship returns null.

Comment: Have you tried using the Laravel QueryBuilder? [Example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins)

Comment: I started down that route, but I ruled it out as the item table is on one database, the other two tables are on a different one. The models are set to connect to the relevant DB, so I thought eloquent would be a better way to do this. The attributes and categories table are in a legacy system that I have limited access to

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$items = Item::with('attributes.category')->get();
```

So you access the `category` relationship inside the `attributes` relationship.

For example:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    foreach ($item->attributes as $attribute) {
        echo $attribute->category->id; // Will print the category id.
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but still not getting a result.  I've updated the question to include the models as they are currently